# serializer.data generating exception , how to debug it

Tags: django-rest-framework

The serializer is not returning any data what is the issue , how to debug it

class CoachDrillDownSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

```
drill_down_cohertinfo = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

def get_drill_down_cohertinfo(self, obj):
    try:
        request = self.context.get("request")
        data = Usersessions.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        serializer = CohertinfodrilldownSerializer(data, many=True, context={"request": request}, read_only=True)
        print(serializer.data)
        print("come true")
        return serializer.data
    except:
        print("error")
        return []
```

Comment: remove the `except` clause and let the exception raise.

Comment: The data is queryset here but when received by CohertinfodrilldownSerializer its just a object of Usersessions so the .count() is not working.Any suggestions

Comment: Thanks it was a issue with many=True , I removed it and its started working.
Thanks for letting me know how to debug this